# Doxygen how to inherit documents from overriden methods in a generic interface?

Tags: java, generics, doxygen

I have an interface `Collection<T extends Item>`, and a class that implements that interface `Movies implements Collection<Movie>`.  The interface has a couple of abstract methods for sorting that are overriden by Movies.

What I want to know is, how can I get Doxygen to use the documentation from Collection.sort() and Collection.safeSort() in the class Movies?  It'd be useful to know because then I can write the documentation for the interface, rather than each implementation of the interface.  If I could -add- documentation to the overridden methods, that would be great, but that's not 100% necessary.

`INHERIT_DOCS` is set to `YES` by the way, I believe Doxygen is struggling because it implements `Collection<Movie>` and not `Collection<T extends Item>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There appear to be a number of bugs filed against doxygen related to this type of behavior, see the following for some examples:

- https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=516656
- https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=583958
- https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=631675

For a workaround, you could use @copydoc to bring the documentation in your base class in to your derived class, something like:

```
/**
 * Movies
 */
public class Movies extends Collection<Movie> {
    /**
     * @copydoc Collection<T extends Item>::sort()
     *
     * Additional documentation specific to Movies::sort().
     */
    public void sort(void) { return; }
}
```

This will allow the documentation in the base class to appear to in the derived class documentation without having to copy it.

Comment: Thanks.  I have actually refactored the code for other reasons now, but it's useful to know for the future.